# Host names or IP addresses for outgoing firewall config

Tags: azure-iot-edge

I need to configure a firewall to limit the outgoing connectivity for an Azure IoT Edge device, is the a list of IPs or hostnames for the Azure IoT Hub/Edge servers that I can put in the firewall rules?

I have already determined that I can limit the outgoing ports to 443, 5671 and 8883, but I am asked to also limit connection on an IP level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure IoT Hub does not expose certain IP addresses or ranges. You can only do this on DNS level. See here for general guidance on required connections for IoT Edge: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/production-checklist#whitelist-connections
[image]

You can of course replace `*.azure-devices.net` with the DNS name of your specific IoT Hub instance.

Answer (score 0):

Update on this: The Microsoft container registry was recently changed to use OCI specified data endpoints (see [announcement](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-container-registry-mitigating-data-exfiltration-with-dedicated-data-endpoints/) ), meaning you will have to add *.cdn.mscr.io to your firewall. **But** be careful, because this will be changed to *.data.mcr.microsoft.com soon, starting June 15, 2020 (for more details on the [change see](https://github.com/microsoft/containerregistry/blob/master/client-firewall-rules.md))